# How to have a div which covers all of the div which are behind it?

Tags: css

In my header of my each page I have a div with  the following css:

```
.top{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0066a4;
}
```

The problem is when my page is long enough and scroll it down this div with class of "top" conflicts with  other divs in my page! Is there any way that my div for header with class "top" covers all of the other divs from my page witch conflict with it?

I wish I could put an image of my webpage! If you need more clarification ,please let me know. If there is any way I can put an image please let me know how I can do it? Thanks :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.top` class:

```
z-index: 500;
```

[Then read this.](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Comment: Man the same problem!

Comment: Might be worth trying a higher z-index. Better yet, go to codepen.io and paste your html/css/js, then link to it in your post. Helps us troubleshoot your code.